# Minimize the jealousy function

Tags: analysis, maxima-minima

**Given**:
$m$ chocolates and $n$ students with jealousy value $\{j_1, j_2,...j_n\}$ where $0<j_i<100$.

**To Do**:

- Distribute these chocolates among students $\{c_1, c_2,...c_n\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i=m$   and,
- Minimise total jealousy $J(c_1,c_2,..c_n)= \sum_{i=1}^n j_i*x_{c_i}$
  **Note:**

  - $x_{c_i}$ is the number of students who received $>c_i$ chocolates.
  - $j_i*x_{c_i}$ represents jealousy of $i^{th}$ student.
  - $c_i \ge0$. It can be $0$ too.

**Example:**
There are $9$ chocolates and $3$ students with jealousy values $\{10, 20, 30\}.$
$\therefore$ minimum value of total jealousy will be $0$ as we can distribute $3$ chocolates to each student $\implies x_1=x_2=x_3=0$.
If we distributed chocolates as $\{1,4,4\}$
$\implies J = 10*2+20*0+30*0=20$.

Comment: Do you want to do this analytically or numerically?

Comment: No I need proper solution with steps.

Comment: Hmm. Well, first you can reduce $m$ by giving $\lfloor m/n \rfloor$ chocolates to everyone. I conjecture that now the best thing to do is to give one chocolate to each of the remaining students, going from most jealous to least jealous, continuing until you run out of chocolates. This is a "greedy algorithm" for this problem. Can you do any better than that?

Comment: That will not work. Let there be $4$ students with jealousy  $\{8,8,9,9\}$ and there be $6$ chocolates. Now according to you, I will give $\{1,1,2,2\}$ which leads to a jealousy of $32$. I can distribute chocolates as $\{0, 2, 2,2\}$ which leads to jealousy of $24$.

Comment: Cool, so you can do better. How can you make an algorithm that finds your improvement?

Comment: Now that you've pointed it out, I do see a way to make your improvement: after doing my suggestion, begin giving 1 chocolate to each person who hasn't gotten an additional one (in the same order), taking them from the least jealous people (until each of them has none). Continue doing this until you would transfer a chocolate from a more jealous person to a less jealous person. Can you do any better than *that*?

Comment: Also, can you write the result of this algorithm in a simpler way? (I can think of one...)

Comment: That sounds cool, and how can you write the result in a simpler way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46514/discussion-between-maverick-and-ian).

Comment: Well, think about what we've done now: we now have a bunch of the most jealous people who all have the same number of chocolates, and a bunch of the least jealous people who all have no chocolates. How many people get any chocolates, as a function of $m,n$? (This won't have a nice formula but it does have a simple description in terms of divisibility.)

Comment: Your above mentioned algorithm fails. I explained it in the chat but it seems you couldn't read it. Please read them once.

Comment: No, you misunderstood and/or I misspoke: the 4th person has already received an "extra" chocolate so they would not get a chocolate from the 2nd person under my suggestion. Thus with {0,1,2,2} you have only the two least jealous people being unhappy, resulting in J=5.

Comment: That said, this discussion shows that my algorithm is different from what I thought was its simplified form, which was "find the largest $k \leq n$ such that $k$ divides evenly into $m$, then give $m/k$ chocolates to the $k$ most jealous people and none to the rest". In the case when $m$ is prime and greater than $2$ this would result in ${0,0,...,m}$ which as you have noted in this example is not optimal (since ${0,0,...,1,(m-1)/2,(m-1)/2}$ is better).

Comment: @Ian with {0,1,2,2} J = 12. You misunderstood how J is calculated. Jealousy of a person $i$ is $j_i *$ (no of persons having more choclates). So first person jealousy is $2*3$  and second person's jealousy is $3*2$. This adds up to $12$ and not $5$.

Comment: Oh, I see, I forgot about the multiplication by the number of problematic people. In that case maybe there isn't much of a simple heuristic solution to the problem. In particular, I suppose the first solution is better than the second in this case).